# Razor property without a html value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My textboxes look something like this at the moment,

```
 @Html.TextBox("Something", "", new
       {                           
          type = "text",
          min = 1,
          max = 60,
          data_validation_integer_regex = @ValidationPatterns.Integer,
          data_validation_integer_message = @ValidationPatterns.IntegerMessage,
          data_bind = "value: observables.Something"
        })
```

Which renders as

```
   <input data-bind="value: observables.Something" 
          data-validation-integer-message="Some message" 
          data-validation-integer-regex="^[1-9]\d*$" 
          id="Something" 
          max="60" 
          min="1" 
          name="Something" 
          type="text" 
          value="">
```

The validation library we're using [jqBootstrapValidation](https://github.com/ReactiveRaven/jqBootstrapValidation)

I'd like to make some of my fields required, and the way to do so using this library, I'd need to add a tag to the input field like so

`<input id="Something" ... required >`

Razor doesn't allow me to do this though, as it seems to want all parameters in this format

`property="something"` or `property=100`

is my only option reverting to standard html markup if i want to make my fields required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a property with an empty string (`required=""`), then Razor will render it as a valueless attribute.  That is,

```
@Html.TextBox("name", "value", new { attr="something", required="" })
```

Renders as:

```
<input type='text' name='name' id='id' value='value' attr='something' required />
```

Comment: ... and i didn't think of trying that why? :/

Comment: With MVC 5, this does not work. Both `required = ""` and `required = (string)null` in the anonymous object will render `required=""`.